# bash script for not starting more than once

Tags: bash, shell

So I have a bash script which will notify me, if the battery is low.

The script is here

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

BATTERY=$(upower -e | grep 'BAT')

while :
do
    BATTERY_PERCENTAGE=$(upower -i $BATTERY | grep percentage | awk '{ print $2 }' | sed s/'%'/''/g)
    CABLE=$(upower -d | grep -n2 line-power | grep online | awk '{ print $3 }')

    if [[ "$BATTERY_PERCENTAGE" -lt "10" && $CABLE = "no" ]]; then
        notify-send --urgency=critical "WARNING: Battery is about to die"  "Plug in the power cable"
    fi

sleep 60

done
```

So I am currently using the `dwm` window manager with `Arch Linux`. The issue is that if I just close the window manager, & again launch it, it actually shut down all the programs I was using (for instance flameshot & dunst), but it fails to kill my battery script. Here is my autostart script which I am running in `.xinitrc` file.

```bsh
# My .xinitrc file
# This file will run as autostart

dunst &
flameshot &
setxkbmap -option caps:escape &
sxhkd -c ~/suckless/dwm/sxhkdrc &
~/.fehbg &
~/scripts/battery-notification & 
xrdb ~/.Xresources &
exec dwm
```

And I run this file through xorg's startx. If I do a `ps -ef | grep battery-notification`, it shows more than 2 instances (which include battery script & grep).

Answers are appreciated :)

Comment: Please check what you're writing. In the question you say, "_it fails to kill my battery script_", but in [a comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/670144/bash-script-for-not-starting-more-than-once#comment1263625_670180) you say, "_it actually kills all the instances of the battery script_". Which is it?

Comment: @roaima I thought that the "it actually kills all the instances" only applies to Praveen Kumars solution, and that OP therefore considers that solution unsuitable (because one instance should be kept running).

Comment: OP then continues "_I actually need 1 running in the background_" which is still at odds with the question

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

You could add a lockfile mechanism to your script. Just make sure that the lockfile is reliably deleted when the script exits, e.g. by setting a trap:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

lockfile="/var/run/lock/batterystatus.lock"

if [[ -e "$lockfile" ]]; then exit 0; fi

trap 'rm -f "$lockfile"' EXIT
touch "$lockfile"

# ... your actual script code here
```

Please note that in case the script is terminated with `SIGKILL`, the `trap` will not be sufficient to reliably remove the lockfile.

---

After a helpful clarification by Kamil Maciorowski, here is an improved version using `flock`.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

lockfile="/var/run/lock/batterystatus.lock"
exec 100>"$lockfile"
if ! flock -n 100; then exit 0; fi

# ... your actual script here
```

This will create the lockfile if necessary, and redirects the file descriptor `100` (chosen *almost* arbitrarily)<sup>(1)</sup> to the lockfile. It then tries to get a lock on that file descriptor via `flock`. If that succeeds, the lock will be held until the script exits. If, on the other hand, another script instance already has a lock on that file descriptor, the script will exit immediately.

Note that there is no need to clean up the lockfile - the lock performed by `flock` is what's relevant here. This also means that the *existence* of the lockfile doesn't mean the script shouldn't be started - only the presence of a lock on that file does.

The idea is taken from [here](https://www.putorius.net/lock-files-bash-scripts.html). For further reading, have a look at

- [bash flock: exit if can't acquire lock](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7305448/12231187) (here you see that you can even use the script file itself as the lockfile - as already stated, it is only the lock that counts, not the presence/absence of the file).

---

<sup>(1)</sup> If you have Bash > 4.1, you can have the shell [auto-allocate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17030546/12231187) a free file descriptor via the `{variable-name}>redirection-target`-Syntax, as in:

```bash
exec {lockfd}>"$lockfile"
if ! flock -n "$lockfd"; then exit 0; fi
```

The shell will find the next free file descriptor (with the limitation that only descriptor numbers > 9 are used), and store the actually used descriptor  in the variable `$lockfd` for further use.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I see, then you have clarified a (huge) misunderstanding on my part here, thank you :) !

Comment: @AnantGupta You're welcome! If you found the answer useful, please consider [accepting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it so that others facing a similar issue may find it more easily.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it, but this may work:

At the top of your .xinitrc script:

```
trap 'kill 0' EXIT
```

This will kill all processes in your process group. You may not want to exec the dwm at the end. Just give it dwm without the exec; that will keep the parent bash shell open until the dwm dies.

Comment: It doesn't work for me, I added this in my xinitrc file. This won't kill the extra process

`${trap 'kill 0' EXIT} &`

I tried to add the original one that you sent, but it threw some error. Using `$(
trap 'kill 0' EXIT)` also made an error. Also, simply using the command won't kill the extra process running

Comment: @AnantGupta Don't put the ${ or $( in there. The trap command is written in your script exactly as posted. But you said it didn't work? What was the error?

Answer (score -2):

```
You can add below commands to kill the battery script while logging in

ps -eaf | awk 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1}/battery/ && !/awk/{print "kill -9 "$2}'| sh
```

Comment: The problem with it is that it actually kills all the instances of the battery script. I actually need 1 running in the background